# Change custom seekbar values to adjust the look

Tags: java, android, drawable

I am creating an app where you can design your own custom seekbar and have an in-app preview to help out developers. Now I have this XML code to handle the seekbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill"/>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
</item>
```

I use a GradientDrawable in my java code to be able to change the background of the seekbar, but when I do so it doesn't change the background of the seekbar but behind the seekbar. Also when I change the progressDrawable it fills the whole seekbar with the new background and not just the progress made.
I have tried creating a LayerDrawable and a ClipDrawable but I don't now how to change the drawables for these specific items in my layer-list.

Images:
[image: Background]

[image: Progress fill]

Comment: post a link to an image describing the issue

Comment: @pskink I added images to the question

Comment: are you sure that @drawable/progress_fill contains a gradient?

Comment: Yes i am. it does contain a gradient

Comment: try this http://pastebin.com/WY7XB4dG, is it what you want?

Comment: Yes that fixed my problem, if you want to post it as an answer I will approve your answer :)

Comment: oh come in,  it doesn't really answers your question as my Drawable is not created in xml

Comment: But this is what I wanted to achieve, I already replaced my xml drawable for one created in java but it didnt work correctly and this does. It did actually answer my question :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the solution.
You create a drawable array called layers like this:

```
Drawable[] layers = {new ColorDrawable(0xff000044), new ClipDrawable(seekbardraw, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL)};
```

And then instead of `customseekbar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);` you use this:

```
customseekbar.setProgressDrawable(new LayerDrawable(layers));
```